# Session based rollback through tastypie API call example code?

Tags: django, api, rest, session, tastypie

Lets say I have `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` installed in django and I'm using `SessionAuthentication` class for API authentication in tastypie. Within a session I'm doing some changes in models through my API and after that I want to roll back. Can I do it through tastypie? If yes, what method should I execute? I can't find such a method in tastypie docs. Do you have any working example of that?

Answer (score 2):

Django supports [database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), which will commit multiple state changes atomically.  ([Documentation...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/))

It is unclear in your question how you want to trigger the rollback.  One option is to use [request transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests), which will rollback if an unhandled exception is issued by the view function.  If you want more fine grained control, familiarize yourself with the options in the linked-to documentation.  For example, you may explicitly [create a transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) and then [roll it back](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#transaction-rollback) inside your view.

With respect to Tastypie, you may need to place your transaction management inside the appropriate method on the [`Resource` interface](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html).

I hope this gives you some pointers.  Please update your question with more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to commit changes to your models to the database, and then roll them back on a future request?  That's not something that TastyPie supports (or, for that matter, Django or SQL).  It's not really possible to do a clean rollback like that, considering other requests could have interacted with/changed/ built relationships with those objects in the mean time.

The best solution would probably be to integrate something like [Reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) that would allow you to restore objects to a previous state.

If you want to be able to roll back all of the operations during a session, you'd probably need to keep track of the session start time and the list of objects that had been changed.  If you wanted to do a rollback, you'd just have to iterate over that list and invoke `reversion`'s `revert` method, like

```
reversion.get_for_date(your_model, session_start_datetime).revert()
```

However, again, that will also roll back any changes any other users have made in the same time frame, but that will be the case for any solution to this requirement.

Comment: I should note that if you want to roll back changes enacted within a single request or API call, then you should use database transactions as the other answerer mentioned.  However, it is almost never a good practice to leave transactions open across requests, so that's not suitable if you want your rollback period to last longer than the life of your request.